# Is there a way to utilize the Mac Laptops' touchpad pinch gestures on Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, macos, multi-touch, gesture, touchpad

I have written a Google Maps-based application in Flex. Currently you can use the mouse wheel to zoom in and out the map. Is it possible on Mac laptops to use the pinch gesture to zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without some hacking. There's [MultiCluch](http://github.com/whenders0n/multiclutch/tree/master), which is an InputManager that lets you assign gestures to keyboard shortcuts, which might be a starting point.

In any case, you're in for some pain, because there's (currently) no [(public)](http://cocoadex.com/2008/02/nsevent-modifications-swipe-ro.html) way to do this even in Cocoa.